# Как правильно дописать парсер на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests, bs4

Мне надо написать парсер для статей и комментарии к ней, но столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге самих комментариев. Парсер выводит комментарии, но только первый в статье и то много раз. Буду рад помощи. Вот сам код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import json

url = 'https://lainelir2.pythonanywhere.com/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')

items = {}
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='container-link'):
    articles_url = 'https://lainelir2.pythonanywhere.com' + i.a['href']
    articles_name = i.text
    articles_name = articles_name.replace('\n', '') 
    items[articles_name] = articles_url

with open('articles.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(items, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

with open('articles.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for name, url in data.items():

    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')

    for text_articles in soup.find_all('div', class_='container-view'):
        articles_text = soup.find('div', class_='text-view').text 
        comment_text = soup.find_all('a', class_='text-reply')
        print(comment_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for name, url in data.items():

    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')
    
    for comment_text in soup.find_all('a', class_='text-reply'):
        print(comment_text.text)
```

Comment: А можно встроить это в одни цикл ?